# Couldn't configure Elastic Retry or update the kibana.yml file manually

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am tring to configure kibana but I get flowing error

`Couldn't configure Elastic Retry or update the kibana.yml file manually.`

[image]

this is my /etc/kibana/kibana.yml

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601
server.host: '127.0.0.1'
kibana.index: ".kibana"


elasticsearch.username: "user"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"
xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: 706c88e045c127e21b81c902425cdb54
xpack.reporting.encryptionKey: d67296d7d4958bdd1594e965e6b97ab9
xpack.security.encryptionKey: d496d7cb6a5983c213f7902767069744
xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey: 706c88e045c127e21b81c902425cdb54
xpack.reporting.encryptionKey: d67296d7d4958bdd1594e965e6b97ab9
xpack.security.encryptionKey: d496d7cb6a5983c213f7902767069744
```

How can I fix this error?
Please help me.

Comment: you have duplicate keys there, or a copy+paste issue? however what do the Kibana logs themselves show?